# Show the inequality: $\rho(X)\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\rho(X_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need help with the following problem.
Let $$\rho(X):=\inf\{m\in\mathbb{R} : X+m\geq0\,\, \mathbb{P}-a.s\}$$ where $X\in L^{\infty}$. I have to prove that for any bounded sequence $(X_n)_n$ which converges
$ \mathbb{P}$-a.s. to some X,
$$\rho(X)\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\rho(X_n)$$
As first thing I rewrote $\rho(X)$ as
$$\rho(X)=\inf\{m\in\mathbb{R} : \mathbb{E}[1_{\left\{(X+m)\geq0\right\}}]=1\}$$ then we can say that $$\mathbb{E}[1_{\left\{(X+m)\geq0\right\}}]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[1_{\left\{(X_n+m)\geq0\right\}} ]$$ thanks to the dominated convergence theorem. Now I don't know how to proceed, any hint?

Comment: Did you try using Fatou's Lemma on the sequence $\mathbb{1}_{X_n + m \geq 0}$?

Comment: I used dominated convergence theorem that it's stronger... I don't understand. My problem is that I don't get how the limit "comes out" of the bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your convergence is a.s., hence you should think "pointwise" rather than in the notion of expectations, using DCT etc. Proceeding pointwise, you just have to refine your efforts in the "$\omega$-by-$\omega$" direction : fix an $\omega \in \Omega$, see why it's obvious. Now see why things happen for sufficiently many $\omega$.

Namely, $\rho(X_n) = \inf\{m : X_n \geq -m \ \ \mathbb P\text{-a.s.} \}$. Now, $X_n \to X$ a.s. , which means that on a set of $\mathbb P$ measure $1$, $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ holds. Call that set as $\Omega'$.

Let $m_n$ be any sequence such that $\mathbb P(X_n \geq -m_n) = 1$. Then, for a subset $\Omega_n \subset \Omega$ with $\mathbb P(\Omega_n) = 1$, $X_n(\omega) \geq -m_n$ for all $\omega \in \Omega_n$.

Observe that if $\omega \in \Omega' \cap \left(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \Omega\right)$ then $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ and $X_n(\omega) \geq -m_n$ for all $n$, hence by usual properties of limits, $X(\omega) \geq -\liminf_{n \to \infty} m_n$ on $\Omega' \cap \left(\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \Omega\right)$, which by countable additivity occurs with probability $1$.

Now, let $\rho(X_n) = M_n, \liminf \rho(X_n) = M$ and consider $\epsilon>0$ arbitrary. Pick $m_n$ above as $M_n + \epsilon$. By choice, $\mathbb P(X_n \geq -m_n) = 1$, therefore $\mathbb P(X \geq -\liminf m_n) = 1$. However, $\liminf m_n \leq \liminf M_n + \epsilon= M+\epsilon$, therefore $\mathbb P(X \geq -M+\epsilon) = 1$ for all $\epsilon \geq 0$. It follows that $M+\epsilon \in \{m \in \mathbb R : X+m \geq 0 \ \ \mathbb P\text{-a.s.}\}$ for all $\epsilon>0$, hence $\rho(X) \leq M$, as desired.

Perhaps the lesson is that, unless forced to, keep a.s. convergence as an "$\omega$-by-$\omega$" statement for as long as possible, converting probabilistic statements into those involving only a single sample element, and try to proceed from there onwards. Note that I do *not* expect this statement to hold if $X_n \to X$ merely in probability or in distribution ( I could be wrong about convergence in probability, but for convergence in distribution, I'm pretty sure one can hash out a counterexample).